# Shimano Steps error E010 and W013

Tags: shimano, electric-bike

After the last update of the system, which allows optimizing the ECO option with three levels of assistance, Low, Medium and High, in the last 2 trips with the Medium option, several errors have occurred several times: E010 and W013.

Does anybody know if the problem comes from this latest update?

---

<sub>The above is a machine translation of the original post:</sub>

<sub>Después de la última actualizacion del sistema el qual permite optimizar la opción ECO en tres niveles de asisténcia, Low, Medium y Hight, en las 2 últimas salidas con la opción Medium se han producido varias veces los errores E010 y W013, alguién sabe si el problema proviene de esta última actualización.
Gracias</sub>

Comment: Voted to close inline with stack exchange policy that all questions should be in English except on language specific sites:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Comment: @AndyP I already included a translation...

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, and that is a good effort on your part, but against the guidelines, and sets a bad precedent.

Comment: @AndyP So delete the Spanish. There's no need to close questions that can be fixed trivally.

Answer (score 1):

E is for Error.  It is listed as "A system error was detected." with a fix of turn it off and on, and if problems persist see the dealer.   But its not the root cause.

W is for Warning, and that is an alert to tell you something.   W013 means "Initialization of torque sensor was not completed successfully."

The Shimano manual says

> Note: Power assistance may be lower than usual.
>
> Resolution: With your foot off the pedal, press the battery power button and turn on the power again.  If the situation does not improve, contact the place of purchase.

So turn on your bike and then put your foot on the pedal.  If this doesn't help, then your torque sensor or its connecting harness may be damaged.

There is a STEPS manual at https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/um/UM-72F0A-001-00-ENG.pdf or the Spanish language version is at https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/um/UM-72F0A-001-00-SPA.pdf